# Some baseboard in one zone are getting hot and some are not

Tags: heating, baseboard, zoned-heating

So I have one zone with two split loops. One loop is getting hot, the other is not. In the boiler room where the zone splits into two loops i can already feel that one is hot and one is barely warm.

I am assuming that one loop is air locked (although i have no idea how it happened) and this is why half the zone is not getting hot.

The only air bleeder i can find is on the side of the split loop that is hot. When i try to bleed air from it all i get is water, no air.

Am i misdiagnosing the issue? How do i bleed air from the cold loop if the only bleeder is on the hot side?